# System of nonlinear equations in two variables

Tags: systems-of-equations, problem-solving, rational-functions

> Solve: $$\begin{cases}\frac{2}{x+y} - \frac{1}{x-y} = 11\\ \frac{5}{x+y} + \frac{4}{x-y} = 8\end{cases}$$

Please help me out.
I solved this sum but my answer is coming as $x=\frac{1}{32}$ and $y=\frac{7}{32}$ but the correct answer should be $x=-\frac{1}{24}$ and $y=\frac{7}{24}$. How is this coming. Please show with steps.

Comment: If you include your solution in the body of the question we can help you find your errors and show you how to correct them. Please use MathJax to format your math text. Here is a reference: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Set $a=\frac{1}{x+y}, b=\frac{1}{x-y}$ and solve for $a,b$. From this you will get $x+y$ and $x-y$. Now you can solve for $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2):

multiplying by $$x+y$$ and $$x-y$$ we get
$$2(x-y)-(x+y)=11(x^2-y^2)$$
$$5(x-y)+4(x+y)=8(x^2-y^2)$$ thus we get
$$\frac{x-3y}{11}=\frac{9x-y}{8}$$
this can be solved for $x$ or $y$ and you can eliminate one variable

Answer (score 0):

Let $\frac{1}{x+y}=a$ and $\frac{1}{x-y}=b$.

Thus, $2a-b=11$ and $5a+4b=8$, which gives $a=4$ and $b=-3$ or
$$x+y=\frac{1}{4}$$ and $$x-y=-\frac{1}{3},$$which after summing and subtraction  gives
$$(x,y)=\left(\frac{1}{24},\frac{7}{24}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a = \dfrac{1}{x+y}$ and $b = \dfrac{1}{x-y}$, note that one should have $x + y \neq 0$ as well as $x - y \neq 0$. Your system can be rewritten as:
\begin{cases}
2a - b & = 11 \\ 5a + 4b & = 8
\end{cases}
which gives $(a,b) = (4,-3)$. Then solve the system
\begin{cases}
x + y & = \dfrac{1}{4} \\ x - y & = \dfrac{-1}{3}
\end{cases}
which gives the desired solution.